# can't get file from multipartHttpServletRequest.getFile("files") but get A Part from request.getPart("files")

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

this is my full function

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file",headers = "content-type=multipart/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String fileUpload(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) throws IOException {
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    MultipartFile files = multipartHttpServletRequest.getFile("files");
    if(files!=null) {
        //do somethings
        log.info(files);
        return "true";
    }else {
        Part file = request.getPart("files");
        log.info(file.getSize());
        return "false";
    }
}
```

and the `MultipartFile files` is null but the `Part file` is the result which I expected;
why? and how can i get file directly from `multipartHttpServletRequest.getFile("files")`

and my CommonsMultipartResolver config is like this

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(3000000);
    return  commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

Comment: Did  you config the `CommonsMultipartResolver` ?

Comment: sure,i had edited my question

Comment: Where did you put this in your config ?

Comment: @chaoluo i put this in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter ant this is annotationed by Configuration

Comment: show your client side html/ajax

Comment: Could you please  post the request network tracking when upload file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have multipart filter in web.xml. This should be put *before* Spring Security filter chain if you are using that.

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Define multipart resolver as (name is important):

```java
@Bean
public MultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver()
{
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

Since `request.getPart` works you have a recent version of Servlet API and you don't need Commons FileUpload bean/dependency, remove.

Comment: Since it did't worked for therefore I have a question why you are returning `StandardServletMultipartResolver()` when you have another bean with `CommonsMultipartResolver` ?

Comment: @Kramer `StandardServletMultipartResolver` replaces `CommonsMultipartResolver`. The first has the advantage of not to be dependent of Commons FileUpload.

Comment: I posted a question on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650966/upload-a-file-using-commons-multiparthttpservlet-resolver....I have added the filter as you mentioned I created the bean in my config file where I have all the beans required for Rest service to work........can you point out the mistake because I am also getting the file in Part but not the other way