# Upload a file using Commons Multiparthttpservlet resolver

Tags: spring-boot

I made a service in spring boot and front end in Reactjs but my service is not giving anything(no result)

I am uploading form data with file image or audio but I don't receive any file at my Rest Service.

**My Service Class:**

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ServiceResponse save(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String event_name=request.getParameter("event_name");   

        logger.debug("event name: "+event_name);
        logger.debug("Has a file :"+request.getFileNames().hasNext()); // getting false
        if(request.getFileNames().hasNext()) {
           // Working here
            try{}
            catch(Exception e){
              return ServiceResponse.createFailureResponse("Request 
              failed!");
             }      
            }
        return ServiceResponse.createSuccessResponse();


    }
```

**Dependency required:**

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Bean created :**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("com.mphasis.springreact.services.admin")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mphasis.springreact.services.admin")
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class DBConfiguration {

    public DBConfiguration() {

    }

    @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)
        {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DummyApp");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");     
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver createMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver()
    {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

     @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      } 

}
```

[image: Postman service request]

Here is my **frontend** part though service itself not working:

```
 var blob = new Blob(this.state.chunks, {type: 'audio/mp3;codec=opus'});

    var formData=new FormData();

    formData.append("event_name",event);
    formData.append("file",new File([blob], event, {type: 'audio/mp3;codec=opus', lastModified: Date.now()}));
     fetch('http://localhost:6020/uploadFile', {
    method: "POST", 
    mode: "cors", 
    cache: "no-cache", 

    redirect: "follow", 
    referrer: "no-referrer", 
    body: formData, 
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data){ console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) ) });
```

I have missed **web dependency** in service class since I made rest call therefore I don't need it I guess but in most tuturial it was mentioned to have it for multipart file

Comment: I am getting event_name but not file

Comment: Apart from this I am not able to log my data into file but console is working same code I wrote for another module its working

Comment: Looks like you need to annotate with `@MultipartConfig`

Comment: @secretsuperstar nope thing I am getting false in `request.getFileNames().hasNext()` with or without using the above annotation